# Add poll to Video stream using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to add a question/poll to the video stream to make it interactive. I came across ID3 tag helps to do this job with FFMPEG, But I can see, we can only add static details like title, artist, genre..etc metadata with ID3. I have not found any references for this over the internet, Appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you mean interactive elements inside a video stream, or just changing text in the stream that can respond to outside stimulus?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732317/drawing-dynamic-text-on-video-stream

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. ID3 is a metadata container format.